# Is this a good place to ask a question I have about programming?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

I have asked the same question twice about a program on python and it keeps getting put on hold and i thought this was a good place to ask programming questions and I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I just asked it there and they told me to ask it here.

Comment: see [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Comment: [you were told](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238536/is-this-a-good-site-to-ask-programing-questions#comment781681_238536) to post _not_ on main site, and commenter even gave a correct link: "You should probably ask this on the **[programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/)**..."

Comment: I get it I'm going to ask my question on stack overflow.

Comment: note as mentioned in [comments](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254266/building-a-python-password-guesser#comment512088_254266) to your first question: "The specifics of why a given tool doesn't match what you are expecting to see is best asked on Stack Overflow. However, you should **make sure to include the text (code and output) of what you are doing and what you are expecting**. The "password guessing algorithms" as asked is not appropriate anywhere on Stack Exchange. You need to do the research for that yourself."

Comment: why is it not appropriate for stack overflow isn't it for programmers to help other programmers

Comment: see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/839601) In brief, you need to help us help you

Answer (score 7):

You're in the wrong place.

For coding issues you need to ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

This site is for conceptual and design issues.

The simplest explanation is that if you're standing in front of a whiteboard and have a question ask here, if you're sitting in front of an IDE ask on Stack Overflow.

Also if you have one question closed then don't just ask the same question again. Read the reason given in the text inserted just below your question for why it was closed. Follow the links and take the [tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 4):

The question being asked was [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254266/building-a-python-password-guesser) (10k link) (the struck out part is from an earlier revision).

> I have the python shell (IDEL) on my mac, but all of the tutorials i have seen online look different than mine and i was wondering if there is anything else I should download from python to get more than just the shell.  <s>Also does anyone know any password guessing algorithms.</s> Thanks.

To which I had a comment:

> The specifics of why a given tool doesn't match what you are expecting to see is best asked on Stack Overflow. However, you should make sure to include the text (code and output) of what you are doing and what you are expecting. The "password guessing algorithms" as asked is not appropriate anywhere on Stack Exchange. You need to do the research for that yourself.

As described in the help center - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) note the bit:

> **and it is not about...**
>
> coding tools, such as compilers, debuggers, and IDEs (ask on Stack Overflow instead)

The question about how python (and specifically IDLE) is behaving is a question about a coding tool.  Thus, it belongs on Stack Overflow (note the [python-idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-idle) tag there - you should probably look through the existing [python-idle + osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-idle+osx) tagged questions - there are only 31 of them).

If you don't find a question that matches what you are asking, you should ask a question *there*.  To help write a good Stack Overflow question, be sure to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  You will need to at least have the information about python version, osx version, the code you are running, what you are expecting, what your results are and make sure that its formatted well too.

Questions about how to use tools belong on Stack Overflow - not Programmers.SE.  Your question was closed here because it was off topic here and if it was migrated to Stack Overflow, it would likely have been closed there too because of the issues I mentioned previously.

---

The question of 'password guessing algorithms' is something *you* need to search for.  I can think of a dozen off the top of my head.  Because of this, the question of 'what is a good password guessing algorithm' is too broad - there are too many possible answers to it.  You *really* need to just think about this and do some research about it.

Comment: That wording "coding tools, such as compilers, debuggers, and IDEs (ask on Stack Overflow instead)" has now gone from the page linked to. I think it would be useful to have it back.